# Sum of Binomials Raised to a Power

Tags: functional-analysis, power-series

I've run into an interesting sum, and I was wondering if anyone had any closed-form expression, perhaps in terms of special functions. The sum is:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^N \binom{N}{n} \left(1 + x^n \right)^p $$

where $N,p$ are positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a closed-form expression, but there is a nice symmetry.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^N\binom{N}{n}(1+x^n)^p&=\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{j=0}^p\binom{p}{j}x^{nj}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^p\binom{p}{j}\sum_{n=0}^N\binom{N}{n}x^{nj}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^p\binom{p}{j}(1+x^j)^N
> \end{align*}